# How to initiate a batch file for GUI dev using tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, batch-file, tkinter

Hello (nice) community,
A beginner question again. I am learning GUI development and as beginner, I am starting with `tkinter`. All the files I have read are saying to create the code on a notepad and save it in .bat format. I am doing it all as described and saving the file under all file and not .txt files but still I could not get the file running.
Here is an example of the code:
f

```
from tkinter import *
rw = Tk()
rw.title("Graphical User Interface")
rw.geometry("200x100")
#create frames to hold the window's gadgets (widgets)
fr = Frame(rw)
fr.grid()
rw.mainloop()
pause
```

Many many thanks in advance for your valuable time and input.
Cheers

Comment: Your question in its current form (Software recomendation request) is off topic here on stack overflow. As for your stated issue regarding not being able to run a .bat file, no help can be provided unless you provide a minimal reproducable example of your code. Batch scripting is not the same as Python scripting, so there should be no expectation that code that runs in IDLE console would result in a functional .bat file.

Comment: Hello and thank your for your answer. How can I reframe my question or delete it so I can  remove all the part regarding asking for recommendations. Could you advise me where I can post a question regarding GUI dev redommendations other than stackoverflow. Thank you again.

Comment: Software recommendations are opinion based. Meaning I will prefer one, the next person something else etc. Therefore it is a case of researching and  finding what is best for you. As for the batch file not executing, this is where the question comes which we should not need to ask, how do you attempt launching the batch file? I suggest you edit your quesiton and remove the irrelevant part around recommendations, then show your batch file and how you execute it and what happens when you do. This will make the question more on topic.

Comment: ok, that's better. Now.. This is not batch code `:)` that is Python. give it a `.py` extension and open `cmd` then run `python filename.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am posting this answer to better explain. I do not want you to mark the answer as correct as I will be deleting it again. I am simply posting it to help you understand.

find the file on disk and rename it to change extension from `.bat` to `.py`

open `cmd` and `cd` to the relevant dir.

[image]

Now, based on your statement that this did run from console already, I assume you have python installed. So you should simply be able to do:

```
python filename.py
```

For demonstration purposes, I name the file `ben.py`
I ran it and voila:

[image]

So, you don't want to do that all the time. So on your desktop (or where ever you want) create a new text file and edit it. Replace the path and filename below to reflect your path and filename:

```
start "" "python.exe" "z:\path to file\ben.py"
```

Rename the file to `start_gui.cmd` and now you can just double click it.

Comment: Thank your very much Barnard for your help. It worked.

Comment: Rather than working on a notepad and then saving the file as it has been recommended in the book I am reading, I find that making a GUI using an IDE (like vscode) to be easier and more practical. But your tip Barnard made a big difference. thank you again.

Comment: If you are looking for a good editor, look at activestate Komodo IDE.

Comment: Thanks Barnard. I'ill check it out.